# How to get the last page of created PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to print some lines on the last page of my PDF file during its creation step on runtime using mPDF.

Can any show some any working example or piece of code from the mPDF library so I will achieve this easily.

My PHP source code is below which is working fine but I want to write some text on the last page of my PDF file.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = file_get_contents('../styles/uploads/files/extract/'.$bookName.'/'.$bookName.'_coverFinal.php');
$html = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__)."/../styles/uploads/files/pdf_files/PDF_Book_".$var.".pdf", "F");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood you correctly:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = file_get_contents('../styles/uploads/files/extract/'.$bookName.'/'.$bookName.'_coverFinal.php');
$html .= 'your html here';
$html = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__)."/../styles/uploads/files/pdf_files/PDF_Book_".$var.".pdf", "F");
```

in the end $html is just a string

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to use `WriteHTML()` function.So that you would be able to add the text on the page in pdf

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$html = file_get_contents('../styles/uploads/files/extract/'.$bookName.'/'.$bookName.'_coverFinal.php');
$html .= 'the content which you want to add to';
$html = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$html);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__)."/../styles/uploads/files/pdf_files/PDF_Book_".$var.".pdf", "F");
```